# How to upload a file in restassured with java

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have an API which take a file from system and shows on the application, for which I am trying to automate with rest assured and Java

I have tried, changing the image to binary code and then adding it as parameter that does not work.

```
Map<String, String> paramSample = new HashMap<>();
    paramSample.put("api_key", "A813302*************");
    paramSample.put("method", "my");
    paramSample.put("body", "{\n" +
            "  \"to\":\"91xxxxxxxx\",\n" +
            " \"type\": \"image\", \"image\" : {\"caption\" : \"{{caption}}\"},\n" +
            "\"callback\":\"{{callback}}\"\n" +
            "}");
    paramSample.put("from", "91xxxxxxx");
    paramSample.put("file","C:\\Users\\sobhit.s\\Pictures\\SMS-2047.png");
    RequestSpecification request = given();
    Response responseSample = request.params(paramSample).get(ExecutionConfig.BASE_URL).then().extract().response();
    String res=responseSample.prettyPrint();
```

Response is-

```
{
    "status": "xxxx",
    "message": "Invalid file format. Upload valid file."
}
```

Comment: use `given().params(paramSample).multiPart(file)` to send the file in multipart request.

Comment: @SudhirR can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you are unsure, do this in Postman and then recreate the same in code. 
This way you will have a post man to demonstrate your coding problem.

Use `.queryParam()` only for params and not for the body content. Body content should be under `.body()`

Use `.multiPart()` to upload the file as a multi part quest. Hope this helps.

```
given().queryParam(
            "api_key", "A813302*************", 
            "method", "my",
            "from", "91xxxxxxx")
            .body("{\n" +
            "  \"to\":\"91xxxxxxxx\",\n" +
            " \"type\": \"image\", \"image\" : {\"caption\" : \"{{caption}}\"},\n" +
            "\"callback\":\"{{callback}}\"\n" +
            "}")
            .multiPart(new File("C:/Users/sobhit.s/Pictures/SMS-2047.png"))
            .when()
            .get(ExecutionConfig.BASE_URL)
            .prettyPrint();
```

Comment: You are genius man. I was stuck with this from last one month.

Comment: One more question can make this as some kind of function so the values will be pass in function and then it will execute so main code will be hidden. It will be kind of abstraction... let me know what you think.